# Finding the Max of multiple elements in the same column

Tags: sql, sqlite

Table A is given with A.i, A.j, and A.val. A makes a 3x3 matrix.

I need to find the Max(A.val) from A.val where its ij, i+1j, ij+1,i-1j, ij-1 if it exists. However, I can't find any solution to finding the max value of specific elements of the same column. Please help.

Sample:

```
i   |   j   |   val
0       0       7
0       1       5
0       2       8
1       0       10
1       1       7
1       2       7
2       0       2
2       1       0
2       2       5
```

answer output:

i   |   j   |   val

```
0       0       10
0       1       8
0       2       8
1       0       10
1       1       10
1       2       8
2       0       10
2       1       7
2       2       7
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show sample data and expected output so we are sure to understand your requirement. Also, would you please tag your question with the RDBMS that you are using (oracle, mysql, sql-server, ...) ?

Comment: And what would the result set be?  I don't know if I really understand the problem.  Is it one value for the whole table or one value per cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SQLite >= 3.25 (2018), you can use [window functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html). `LAG()` and `LEAD()` let you access the neighbour records. Then, [core function `MAX()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#maxoreunc) can be used to compute the maximum of a list of value.

```
SELECT
    i,
    j,
    MAX(
        val,
        COALESCE(LEAD(val) OVER(PARTITION BY j ORDER BY i), 0), -- i+1 / j
        COALESCE(LAG(val)  OVER(PARTITION BY j ORDER BY i), 0), -- i-1 / j
        COALESCE(LEAD(val) OVER(PARTITION BY i ORDER BY j), 0), -- i   / j+1
        COALESCE(LAG(val)  OVER(PARTITION BY i ORDER BY j), 0)  -- i   / j-1
    ) res
FROM mytable
```

This **[DB fiddle demo on SQLite 3.26](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wWKr7LESYLV6Nc8cx2yfED/1)** with your sample data returns :

```
| i   | j   | res |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0   | 0   | 10  |
| 0   | 1   | 8   |
| 0   | 2   | 8   |
| 1   | 0   | 10  |
| 1   | 1   | 10  |
| 1   | 2   | 8   |
| 2   | 0   | 10  |
| 2   | 1   | 7   |
| 2   | 2   | 7   |
```

---

In earlier versions of SQLite, one solution would be to make 4 joins, as follows :

```
SELECT
    t.i,
    t.j,
    MAX(
        t.val, 
        COALESCE(t1.val, 0), 
        COALESCE(t2.val, 0), 
        COALESCE(t3.val, 0), 
        COALESCE(t4.val, 0)
    ) res
FROM mytable t
LEFT JOIN mytable t1 ON t.i = t1.i + 1 AND t.j = t1.j 
LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON t.i = t2.i - 1 AND t.j = t2.j 
LEFT JOIN mytable t3 ON t.i = t3.i     AND t.j = t3.j + 1
LEFT JOIN mytable t4 ON t.i = t4.i     AND t.j = t4.j - 1
```

**[Demo on db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wWKr7LESYLV6Nc8cx2yfED/2)**

Comment: getting (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "OVER" : syntax error

Comment: @StevenChoi : which version of sqlite are you using ?

Comment: @StevenChoi : updated my answer with a solution for SQLite < 3.25

Comment: ipython-sql 0.3.9

Comment: thanks worked perfectly on the previous version sample

Answer (score 1):

The only sensible interpretation that I can think of is that you want the maximum of the four adjacent cells plus the current cell.  Let me assume that your database supports `greatest()`, because that simplifies the problem:

```
select t.*,
       greatest(val,
                lag(val, 1, val) over (order by i),
                lead(val, 1, val) over (order by i),
                lag(val, 1, val) over (order by j),
                lead(val, 1, val) over (order by j)
               ) as neighborly_maximum                
from t;
```

You can also do this with left join:

```
select t.*,
           greatest(val,
                    coalesce(tup.val, val),
                    coalesce(tdown.val, val),
                    coalesce(tleft.val, val),
                    coalesce(tright.val, val)
                   ) as neighborly_maximum                       
from t left join
     t tup
     on tup.i = t.i and tup.j = t.j + 1 left join
     t tdown
     on tdown.i = t.i and tdown.j = t.j - 1 left join
     t tleft
     on tleft.i = t.i - 1 and tleft.j = t.j left join
     t tright
     on tright.i = t.i + 1 and tright.j = t.j;
```

Comment: getting (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "OVER" : syntax error